# How can I update my API's fetch URL params with a form input field?

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I'm trying to update my API's fetch URL params with data submitted by a form input field, but I can't figure out how to do so.

More specifically, I'm using ipify geolocation API and need to update the fetch URL with an IP address submitted by the user. I'm currently just storing the user input as a state variable `userIp`, which I'd like to pass into the API fetch URL.

I'm new to react and nextjs and can't seem to figure out what to search for to help me understand this, all the tutorials I can find don't cover this. Any help would be greatly appreciated

api/ip.js

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const ip = "" // placeholder, this should be value of userIp on index.js
  const url = `${process.env.IPIFY_URL}apiKey=${process.env.IPIFY_API}&ipAddress=${ip}`
  
  const data = await fetch(url)
  .then(res => res.json())

  res.json(data); 
}
```

index.js

```
import { useState } from "react"

const home = () => {

  const [info, setInfo] = useState([])
  const [userIp, setUserIp] = useState('') // user input ip address

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetchIp()
  };

  const fetchIp = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/ip')
    const data = await response.json()
    setInfo(data)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="IP"
          value={userIp}
          onChange={(e) => setUserIp(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>

      <p>{info.ip}</p>
      <p>{info.location?.city}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default home;
```

Comment: where do you import api/ip.js in index.js?

Comment: I'm not, didn't think I needed to since I'm fetching the API route in fetchIp()

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are passing the `userIp` as a parameter to the `/api/ip` route:

```
  const fetchIp = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/ip/${userIp}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setInfo(data);
  };
```

You will need to declare your api file in the folder `pages/api/ip` and call it `[ip].js`.
Finally, you will be able to access the `ip` parameter via the `req.query` object in your handler:

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { ip } = req.query
  ...
}
```